# Selection Histogram Axis Data Update

Tags: python, histogram, bokeh, axes

I created, using bokeh, a selection histogram that contains a central scatter plot and histograms as the axes. I also have a legend that displays the names of the groups of scatter data that, when clicked, will hide the associated data points to the legend name. I am wondering, however, if it is possible to update the histogram data as the scatter plot data is being updated (i.e., displayed or hidden).

Keep in mind I am new to python and bokeh and writing concise script in general so some of the code might be fluff, but any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models import BoxSelectTool, LassoSelectTool, Spacer
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, curdoc
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from bokeh.models import CategoricalColorMapper
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.io import export_png
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4

data1 = pd.DataFrame({'m/z': np.random.random(100), 'RT': np.random.random(100)})
data2 = pd.DataFrame({'m/z': np.random.random(100), 'RT': np.random.random(100)})
#create array data from each data set for scatter plot
array_data1 = np.array(data1)
array_data2 = np.array(data2)
#create histogram data
##combine 'm/z' values from each data set into new object
x1 = data1[['m/z']]
x2 = data2[['m/z']]
x = pd.concat([x1,x2])
##combine 'RT' values from each data set into new object
y1 = data1[['RT']]
y2 = data2[['RT']]
y = pd.concat([y1,y2])

#create scatterplot figure
p = figure(x_axis_label='m/z',y_axis_label='RT',tools="", 
plot_width=600, plot_height=600, min_border=10, min_border_left=50,
       toolbar_location="above", title="Mass Recovery Comparison")

p.background_fill_color = "#fafafa"
p.select(BoxSelectTool).select_every_mousemove = False
p.select(LassoSelectTool).select_every_mousemove = False

#create loop for scatter plot
for data, name, color in zip([array_data1,array_data2], ['035','044'], 
    Spectral4):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.columns = ['m/z','RT']
    p.scatter(df['m/z'], df['RT'], line_width=2, color=color, 
    alpha=0.8, legend=name)

#legend formatting
p.legend.location = "top_right"
p.legend.click_policy="hide"

#create horizontal histogram
hhist,hedges = np.histogram(x,bins=20)
hzeros = np.zeros(len(hedges)-1)
hmax = max(hhist)*1.1

ph = figure(toolbar_location=None, plot_width=p.plot_width, 
plot_height=200, x_range=p.x_range, y_range=(0, hmax), min_border=10, 
    min_border_left=50, y_axis_location="right")
ph.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
ph.yaxis.major_label_orientation = np.pi/4
ph.background_fill_color = "#fafafa"

ph.quad(bottom=0, left=hedges[:-1], right=hedges[1:], top=hhist, 
    color="white", line_color="#3A5785")

#create vertical histogram
vhist, vedges = np.histogram(y, bins=20)
vzeros = np.zeros(len(vedges)-1)
vmax = max(vhist)*1.1

pv = figure(toolbar_location=None, plot_width=200, 
    plot_height=p.plot_height, x_range=(0, vmax),y_range=p.y_range, 
    min_border=10, y_axis_location="right")
pv.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
pv.xaxis.major_label_orientation = np.pi/4
pv.background_fill_color = "#fafafa"

pv.quad(left=0, bottom=vedges[:-1], top=vedges[1:], right=vhist, 
    color="white", line_color="#3A5785")

layout = column(row(p, pv), row(ph, Spacer(width=200, height=200)))

show(layout)
```

Comment: Hi, it's not really clear exactly what you are asking, so I tried to just run the code. But the formatting is off, and there is a missing CSV file that you have have not provided. Additionally, there is alot of extraneous code here related to formatting, visuals, etc. It's always much more helpful if you can pare the code down to the bare minimum needed to discuss a particular.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the input. I edited the code a bit to get rid of some of the unnecessary stuff, as well as added some comments regarding purpose of sections of the code. Not sure how to attach the files that are being used, but the files consist of two columns titled 'm/z' and 'RT' and contain floats (ex. 4.569 for 'RT' and 349.567 for 'm/z'). You could make your own files with the file names in the code and have something like two rows for each file, just to see how the code runs.

Comment: Now that the code is smaller it easier to see things. If you want to update the histograms, then you probably want to be [Running a Bokeh Server Application](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/dev/docs/user_guide/server.html) There's already a complete example of a histogram updating (based on selection in this case) here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/selection_histogram.py Otherwise, your only options would be to *re-compute the histogram in JavaScript* or *pre-compute all possible histograms* and send their data up front. Is pre-computing everything acceptable?

Comment: Right that's where I got most of the code from, but the problem is the 'update' function they define at the end of the code is performed on the scatter data labeled 'r'. However, my scatter data is embedded in a for loop which makes it inaccessible (at least with my knowledge) and that's why I posted online, to see if there's a way around the for loop to access the scatter data. For your question, I don't know JavaScript so for now, that wouldn't be an option.

Comment: Well, using `show` implies a standalone Bokeh doc, *not* a Bokeh server app. If you want to have a Bokeh server app (i.e. have real python callbacks) then this will need changes. Bokeh apps usually end with a line like `curdoc().add_root(...)` and are run with `bokeh serve app.py` and *not* with `python app.py` In any case, you already have access, standard python semantics means you can read the variables defined outside the function, i.e. the two separate data frames.

Comment: I have run it on a Bokeh server, but I don't have the code yet to complete the callback I'm looking for, such as the 'update' function in the  example code. The problem I'm having with the for loop is I need to assign a variable name to the scatter data, so I can call the update function on it outside of the loop. I'm not sure how to do this....I hope this makes sense. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not able to understand what your question is really asking. Perhaps someone else will have a better time than me .

Answer (score 1):

The best I am able to interpret is that you want to be able to do something whenever a specific glyph is hidden or muted (or unhidden or unmuted) from an interactive legend.  The following code illustrates how to do that in a general sense, you'd want to replace the `print` with real code that does whatever updates you actually intend:

```
from functools import partial

import pandas as pd

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG

p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=250, x_axis_type='datetime')
p.title.text = 'Click on legend entries to hide lines'

def update(name, attr, old, new):
    # click the legend and see the information print in the console
    print(name, new)

for data, name, color in zip([AAPL, IBM, MSFT, GOOG], ["AAPL", "IBM", "MSFT", "GOOG"], Spectral4):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    r = p.line(df['date'], df['close'], line_width=2, color=color, alpha=0.8, legend=name)
    r.on_change('visible', partial(update, name))

p.legend.location = 'top_left'
p.legend.click_policy = 'hide'

curdoc().add_root(p)
```